# How to search a specific selector through all preceding siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

When traversing DOM with jQuery, is there an easy way to know how many siblings have a particular class **before** my selector ?

For example with the following HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li class="foo">Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li class="active">Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>  
    <li class="foo">Eight</li>  
</ul>
```

from li.active i would like to know that i have 2 li (One and Five) with the 'foo' class preceding my active object.

Can i do that without parsing all the siblings and comparing indexes ?

I thought .prevAll() could help me but it wouldn't find more than the first sibling encountered..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.active').prevAll('.foo').length
```

This will return the length of a set of all previous siblings having a class of `foo`

Comment: Thanks, i thought prevAll was the same as prevUntil except including the matching selector.. I should pay more attention to what i read!

Answer (score 0):

`.prevAll(".foo")` should be all that you need.

```
$(".active").prevAll(".foo");
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/98mCc/).**